# Slow spring component scan

Tags: java, performance, spring, classpath, java-web-start

i found some posts dealing with this topic, but our situation is a bit different, so I post it here, hoping someone can help us with it.
The situation is:
We develop a rich client that is started via webstart (loaded from a server). In the client we use spring (3.0.5) for dependency injection, nothing else so far.
Since we had big trouble with slow component scans because of AOP in spring, we do not use all spring jars but the following:

```
spring-asm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-support-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
```

The effect we have is strange:
If we start the rich client via webstart it is quite fast (component scan in a few seconds). 
Now (for some reason) i try to start our client as regular application by just having all jars on my computer and starting the app with a huge classpath.
In this scenario it takes 3-5 minutes (depending on the computer) to boot the app.
In the log i can see its the spring component scan that takes so long.
Of course the used jar files are 100% identical in both solutions.
So my fundamental question is: Where is the difference here?
I would have expected it all the way round. Long time in Webstart and fast as application.
Does anyone have a hint what could cause those long startup times in the application scenario?

Comment: "and starting the app with a huge classpath" is this the same huge classpath as with the webstart version?

Comment: *"Thanx  
Volker"* 1) Don't include sigs. in questions. 2) Please use the correct spelling for words like 'you', 'your' & 'please'.  This makes it easier for people to understand and help.

Comment: the classpath is the same

Comment: Have you found a solution? I am having the same problem.

Comment: Sorry, we did not find a solution for this. Some day we moved on to a higher spring version (4.X) and the problem was not reported anymore. Nevertheless we still try to improve speed here. With Spring 5 I heard they will offer tools to scan the code and create beans.xml configs to explicitly name all found annotated classes => a scanning should not be necessary anymore. I am not sure if this is really true but if, then it should improve the performance (hopefully)

Comment: We have the problem using Spring 4.3. The scanning of 100 beans takes 30 seconds. I couldn't find the new feature in Spring 5, but we wrote a similar tool ourselves. During the build we write a XML config and don't use scanning in production. That way the application-context initializes instantly.